Impact of accrual on bond total return
A bond pays 30% annual coupons, the next coupon is in 1 month and the bond will mature in 13 months, reimbursement at maturity is 100.
Assuming the same clean price in both scenarios (90), no FX risk, no reinvestment of coupons, and the bond is held until maturity.
2 scenarios
1) I buy bond immediately after the coupon
cash flows until maturity:
OUT: clean price only  = 90
IN:  Notional+coupon in 13 months = 130
at maturity total return = (130-90)/90 = 44%
in this case the YTM will be very close to the total return of the bond
2) I buy the bond immediately,
cash flows until maturity:
OUT: clean price + accrual for 11 months = 90 + 30 * (11/12) = 117.5
IN: coupon in 1 month and  Notional+coupon in 13 months = 30 + 100 + 30 = 160
at maturity total return = 160/117.5 - 1 = 36%
in this case the YTM will be above  the total return of the bond because YTM doesn't keep into account the the accrual?
==> Based on the above it seems it's better from buying after the cpn. Does this make  sense and how to derive a general rule for the impact of accrual on the total return of a bond?

This is not a fair comparison, the timings of cashflows and any reinvestment at risk free or successive interest rates are ignored. The 30 + 100 + 30 = 160 is invalid becuase those specific cashflows occur at different times. If you took the 30 you receive at the next coupon and invest it in the same bond you get 39 at maturity. Then 169 /117.5 is basically the same.

to my question i have added I am assuming no coupon reinvestment. I should have included it before to avoid misunderstandings.

If you break down your question into its respective components it reads like this:

I pay 90 and get back 130, so my return is $\frac{130}{90}-1$=44%.

I pay out 117.5 (and get back 30 almost immediately which accrues no interest going forward) and get back another 130 at maturity. I evaluate my return as $\frac{160}{117.5}-1$=36%.


So yes option 1) will always look better because of the mathematical fact:
$$ \frac{b}{a} \ge \frac{b+k}{a+k}; \quad b>a>0, k>0 $$
I uphold the view that the comparison is meaningless, because you have introduced an additional 30 (which is $k$) which accrues at 0% so the overall return has to be lower.
But the overall answer is, yes it is better (assuming no default) to invest all of your money returning 40%, than to invest part of it returning 40% and some of it returning 0%.
